What is the rubberiest gluten free sponge cake recipe you have come across?
Many years ago, I made some gluten free bread. At the time, I thought that the bread was horrible. It contained the same amount of air bubbles as a sponge cake, and it was very rubbery.
However, I am now thinking about making vegan sausages, and a rubbery gluten free cake batter would help.
What is the rubberiest gluten free sponge cake recipe you have come across?

Not a sponge, but something like a kueh lapis batter (without the layers, just one big mass) might work.
